# Google Maps : Custom icon & Label for Every Marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have found a code to show Google maps with multiple markers using JQuery & xml.

see live [Example](http://www.hostfier.com/markers/markers.html)

I have marker.js like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#map").css({
        height: 500,
        width: 800
    });
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.74033553, 83.25067267);
  MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

  $("#map");
        MYMAP.placeMarkers('markers.xml');
  });

var MYMAP = {
  map: null,
    bounds: null
}

MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:zoom,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml){
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
            var address = $(this).find('address').text();                                 

                        var icon = $(this).find('icon').text();

            // create a new LatLng point for the marker



            var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
            var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

            // extend the bounds to include the new point
            MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({                                
                position: point,
                map: MYMAP.map
            });



            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
            });
            MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
        });
    });
}
```

& xml code I am using.

```
<marker>
<name>.hu</name>
<address>near Viswa Teja School, Thatichetlapalem, Visakhapatnam</address>
<lat>47.29</lat>
<lng>19.05</lng>
</marker>
```

What I want is **custom marker icon & Label for Every marker**.

Is it possible to work within above codes ?

OR how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After Lots of Googling & experimenting I have finally settled to this. An easier way to 
customize your Gmaps.

Hope this will help for newbies here, like me!

DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RaFH5/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with something like the following:

```
    new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude), 
        map: MYMAP.map, 
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("<REPLACE_WITH_MARKER_IMAGE_URL>")});
```

Also, [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Icons) is the relevant documentation.

Comment: Yes, but this way can only apply for normal marker. How about marker of Directions (such as http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#directions_simple)?